# Android Native to Flutter not working in master channel

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am integrating **Flutter** app module in Native Android and IOS applications. I am facing issue with `master channel` with **Android to Flutter**. `io.flutter.facade.Flutter` is not generating in master channel working fine in stable channel. In IOS, code working fine in master channel.

Answer (score 1):

`io.flutter.facade.Fluter` packages is now deprecated in the latest master channel. Please see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects.

Also, I think since this is an issue with an SDK, please consider filing an issue in [Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) repo on Github if you have any more concerns.